# MySQL: Use column-alias in Join statement and Join Statement order?

Tags: php, mysql, join

Just a small MySQL Statement example:

```
SELECT    m.nameMarket nm, m.idCity idc, c.cityname cn 
FROM      markets m 
LEFT JOIN cities c ON m.idCity = c.idCity
```

works as expected. Why does neither of both work here (using the alias in the Select-Clause in the Join-Statement):

```
SELECT    m.nameMarket nm, m.idCity idc, c.cityname cn 
FROM      markets m 
LEFT JOIN cities c ON idc = c.idCity

OR:

SELECT    m.nameMarket nm, m.idCity idc, c.cityname cn 
FROM      markets m 
LEFT JOIN cities c ON m.idc = c.idCity
```

Or can I never use a column-alias in the Join Statement? (Im confused because I can also use a table-alias in the statement as done in the first SQL-code).

And second question is: Is the sequence of the statement in Left Join relevant? I.e.:

```
SELECT    m.nameMarket nm, m.idCity idc, c.cityname cn 
FROM      markets m 
LEFT JOIN cities c ON m.idCity = c.idCity

SELECT    m.nameMarket nm, m.idCity idc, c.cityname cn 
FROM      markets m 
LEFT JOIN cities c ON c.idCity = m.idCity
```

I mean the result is the same, but is there any speed/performance issue or something else related to it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does neither of both work here (using the alias in the Select-Clause in the Join-Statement)?

As you've discovered, column aliases in the `SELECT` clause do not work in other clauses.  In some RDBMSs they work in the `ORDER BY` clause, and less commonly in the `WHERE` clause, but most often they don't.  The reason is simply because the database engine doesn't look at or assign aliases in the `SELECT` clause until very late in the query's execution.  The only exception is in subqueries.

> Is the sequence of the statement in Left Join relevant?
>
> I mean the result is the same, but is there any speed/performance issue or something else related to it?

I would expect the database engine to parse the queries exactly the same.  I would go so far as to say there is a bug in the database engine if it doesn't.

Fire up the MySQL query analyzer and take a look at the execution plans with the `EXPLAIN` command.  They should be identical.

Answer (score 1):

Think about when you select something and alias it.  It doesn't exist until you select it (what if it's a subset of something for example).  So, does it make sense to do a join on an alias that doesn't exist yet?  It's basically the last thing that's applied to the entire statement as it's ran.

A table already exists - so it makes sense to reference that with an alias.  Usually however, you have to make a separate reference to refer to that table again during the query.  This prevents ambiguity if you end up doing multiple joins on the same table.

And does the order matter? Well, the query optimizer will try all sorts of permutations and choose the best one. So no, it shouldn't.